# SQL Server - validate table column values against with values provided

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

I have the following task that want to solve using SQL Server's query and/or stored procedure, and I would really appreciated if someone can give me some directions.

Basically we have a data warehouse based on SQL Server. I want to validate columns in certain tables to ensure the values in these columns are valid.

Example as below:

Table1 `ColumnsToValidate` specifies the table/columns in which values need to be validated. In the example I want to validate the `Gender` column of the `Customer` table, and the `State` column of the `Address` table. And the `validationID` is a foreign-key to a table holding all the valid values (`Table2`).

Table2 `ValidationValues`: this table holds all valid values for specific validation rules. In the example, validation rule #1 (`ValidationID = 1`) has two valid values, and validation rule #2 specified 3 valid values.

I'd like to (using SQL) dynamically create a query based on values in Table 1, which accordingly selects the `Customer.Gender` column and the `Address.State` column, so the values in these columns can be validated against the values in Table 2.

Table1: **ColumnsToValidate**

```
TableName  |   ColumnName   |  ValidationID
-----------+----------------+-----------------
Customer   |    Gender      |   1       
Address    |    State       |   2
```

Table2: **ValidationValues**

```
ValidationID | Values  
-------------+----------------
1            | Male      
1            | Female       
2            | NY      
2            | WA        
2            | CA
```

Table3: **Customer**

```
CustomerID | Gender  
-----------+----------------
111        | Male      
112        | Female       
113        | Unknown      
114        | NULL
```

Table4: **Address**

```
AddressID  | State   
-----------+----------------
211        | AL      
212        | NY       
213        | WA      
214        | NULL
```

EDIT: I could write this in a C# program, but the program will be slow. I would think there could be a way in pure SQL (SQL Server)

Comment: just wish upon a star

Comment: @maSTAShuFu too hard?

Comment: Here's a good start: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Then, once you have that down, move onto this one: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @MichaelC if you let us do the imagination it will take ages... so just wish for now that what you want to do will appear in your OP.

Comment: @EricBrandt It's not a homework question. It's related to a work problem I'd to resolve. I made up the data in the case so I hope it can be more easily understood. But, I felt the problem is actually hard (not at homework level) at least for me. I don't expect full answer, but I'd like to get some directions, such as how to dynamically construct SQL based on table values. In regards of the formatting, I hope I have done enough for the problem to be illustrated- but I am new here, so let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Jump right to the spaghetti DBA post, then. The point is that you haven’t tried anything, or at least you haven’t shown us what you have tried. Which, I think, is what @maSTAShuFu is getting at, too.

Comment: An Option: You can create a table where you can insert the validation details after validating tables and use a store procedure to validate it by scheduling it in a job in the SQL Server Agent for the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, in two steps -

1) To validate the values "as if" the target table and column are known, e.g. the following outer join query finds invalid values on the **Customer.Gender** column.

```
select * from Customer a
left join ValidationValues b
on a.Gender = b.values
and a.ValidationID = b.ValidationID 
where b.values is null
```

2) Use dynamic-SQL to generate above SQL script, using values from table **ColumnsToValidate**, substituting table-name 'Customer' and column-name 'Gender' with variables @tab and @col1 :

```
declare @tableCursor cursor,
        @tab varchar(100),
        @col1 varchar(100),
        @val_id varchar(20)

set @tableCursor = cursor for select * from ColumnsToValidate

open @tableCursor
fetch next from @tableCursor into @tab, @col1, @val_id
while(@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    --dynamic sql
    declare @sql varchar(max)

    set @sql = 

    N'select * from '+ @tab +' a ' +
    N'left join ValidationValues b ' +
    N'on a.' + @col1 + ' = b.values ' +
    N'and a.' + @val_id + ' = b.ValidationID ' +
    N'where b.values is null'

    --print @sql
    exec @sql

    fetch next from @tableCursor into @tab, @col1, @val_id
end

close @tableCursor
deallocate @tableCursor
```

As being said, these are mock-up codes and they are not tested. However I'd just to share the ideas to people having similar problems - the key to the solution is "Dynamic SQL".